# Div dissapear on click outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, components

So i have this **searchbar** ,that when the user types any letter that's been contained in any of my articles,the **div pops up** and show the related articles,but then,unless i backspace,it offcourse stays there,so i would like it to **dissapear after i clicked somewhere** else.My project is in **React**,so i have found many solutions in vanilla JS but none of them seem to work,in my project at least

```css
.autocom-box {
    position: absolute;
    right: 57vw;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    z-index: 9;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(41, 57, 85);
    width: 25vw;
}

.autocom-box li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.autocom-box li :hover {
    background-color: rgb(64, 89, 133)
}

.autocom-box li  {
    height: 8vh;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; /*removes underline*/
    width: 75%;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3vh;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


export default function Header(){
    
    const [articles,setArticles] = useState([])
    const [search,setSearch] = useState('')
    const [searchResults,setSearchResults] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
    const results = articles.filter((article) =>
      ((article.title).toLowerCase()).includes(search.toLowerCase()));
      setSearchResults(results);
  },[articles,search])
   
    const autocom = document.getElementById('autocom-box')
    const hideOnClickOutside = (e) =>{
        if (e.composedPath().includes(autocom)) {
            alert('click insdide')
        }else{
            alert('click outside')
        }
    }
    return(
<div className="search">
   <form onSubmit={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();}}>
       <input type="text" id="input" name="input" autoComplete='off' placeholder="Αναζήτηση..." value = {search} onChange={(e)=>{setSearch(e.target.value)}}/>
    </form>
</div>
<div className="autocom-box" id="autocom-box" >
   <ul onClick={hideOnClickOutside}>
       {searchResults.map( (item,index)=>{
           if (search.length>0){
                 return (<li> {item.title}</li>)      
              }
        })}   
   </ul>
 </div>
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this custom hook, to execute callback function when you click outside the target element.

***Code with javascript***

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

/**
 * Hook that alerts clicks outside of the passed ref
 */
export default (ref, callbackFunc) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    /**
     * Alert if clicked on outside of element
     */
    function handleClickOutside({ target }) {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(target)) {
        callbackFunc()
      }
    }
    // Bind the event listener
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // Unbind the event listener on clean up
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref]);
}
```

***Code with Typescript***

```js
import { useEffect, RefObject } from "react";

/**
 * Hook that alerts clicks outside of the passed ref
 */
export default (ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>, callbackFunc: Function) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    /**
     * Alert if clicked on outside of element
     */
    function handleClickOutside({ target }: MouseEvent) {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(target as Node)) {
        callbackFunc()
      }
    }
    // Bind the event listener
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // Unbind the event listener on clean up
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref]);
}
```

***The hook accept two parameters***

1. The element reference
2. The callback function, which in your case inside you will set the state which depends on it you will hide the element.

Please check this example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-frog-vfn6zc

Comment: The callback function passed will be the onclick function on the div i want to hide?

Comment: No, the callback function is the setState which will hide the input, I just update the answer with a live example, please have a look.

Comment: In the example, whatever you click outside the input, it will hide.

Comment: The sandbox appears as an empty project for me

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure, why the link doesn't update with my code, but I just updated it again.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work,instead of hiding the autocom div,it hides the input box

Comment: That's pretty easy, just add the template reference in the autocomplete div, and add the hide state on it too, I just update the code.

Comment: yeah i tried it,for some reason it still doesn't work ,i don't get why,it seems like it should be working

Comment: Could you provide a full example of your code on a live code editor like codesandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bird-24kcnl?file=/src/Header.js , sorry for my late response

Comment: No problem, but the code sandbox is with empty files.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bird-24kcnl?file=/src/Header.js try one more time,i think it should be ok now

Comment: Still, some files are empty like Home.js, Menu.js, Header.css and useClickOutside.js

Comment: Make sure to save each file before forking it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bird-24kcnl?file=/src/App.js third time is the charm i hope :D

Comment: It's working now, please check.
https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-frog-rhj0t5?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028037/19330634) help you ?

```
const outsideClickListener = event => {
        const deltaX = event.offsetX - lastMouseDownX;
        const deltaY = event.offsetY - lastMouseDownY;
        const distSq = (deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY);
        const isDrag = distSq > 3;
        const isDragException = isDrag && !lastMouseDownWasOutside;

        if (!element.contains(event.target) && isVisible(element) && !isDragException) { // or use: event.target.closest(selector) === null
          element.style.display = 'none';
          removeClickListener();
          document.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownListener); // Or add this line to removeClickListener()
        }
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: unfortunately i get error for most of the values { lastMouseDownX; isVisible(element); !isDragException }

Comment: Please show errors instead of mentioning them